# I failed an exam

Tags: phd, exams

So I had to sit some exams as part of a training course designed to introduce me to the theory I'll be studying on my PhD.

Sadly I had a feeling that I'd not done terribly well on one of them and that was confirmed earlier this weekend when I found I'd missed the passmark by 4 marks. As far as I know it's not essential to the project that I pass but I'm embarrassed to discuss it with my supervisor, especially since it'll be raised in my upcoming annual review.

Moreover, I'm worried it'll end up with me being fired

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/167687/68109

Comment: @Our it's more of a discussion point about how I can feel better about failure.

Comment: @Roberto_1986, this isn't a "discussion" site.

Comment: @Buffy thank you for your valuable input to my situation. I asked for advice.